# How to log array value without hard coding position in the array?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, input

I have a loop that gets input from three different input boxes. The loop works fine for logging the inputs but I am trying to log the values from the input without specifying and hard coding the exact location.

```js
var getInput = $("input");
for (var i = 0; i < getInput.length; i++)
  console.log(getInput[i].id, " => Input", i, " = ", getInput[i].value);
```

I can use `console.log(index[1])`, `console.log(index[2])`, `console.log(index[3])`, etc etc but the problem is I have a table that can have additional rows. So their might be one, two, three rows, etc so as you can imagine hard coding every single index does not make sense. What I am trying to figure out is how to log the value of the input without specifying the index position but instead use the attribute or id of the variable. So if I have

```html
<input
  type="text"
  id="DEPLOYER_PROJECT"
  name="Project Name"
  class="vcheck"
  placeholder=""
> 
<input
  type="text"
  id="OBJ_TYPE"
  name="OBJ_TYPE"
  class="vcheck"
  placeholder=""
>
```

than I am trying to log all instances of OBJ_TYPE or `console.log(getInput[OBJ_TYPE]));`

The reason for this is I have to insert the data into a database (I know about sql injection this is temp)

DB(INSERT INTO TABLE(DEPLOYER_PROJECT, OBJ_TYPE) VALUES ('" + getInput[1] + "', '" + getInput[2] + "'))

As you can imagine hardcoding the array works fine with only one instance of each instance but if the tables has additional rows I can't just hard code getInput[3], getInput[4], getInput[5], getInput[6], etc. The goal is where ever there an input with the id OBJ_TYPE it would take the input associate with it and insert it into the Database with the correct position already assume.

Comment: change the selector to be more specific then: `var getInput = $("input#OBJ_TYPE")` (and at that point you don't need to specify it's an input, because each ID should only exist on at most one element in the document)

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. In `console.log(index[1])`, what is `index`? Where did that come from? The code at the top of your question doesn't seem relevant to the rest

Comment: Sorry I update my question to be reflect what I am asking

Comment: What DB and connection library are you using in the backend? How are you sending the data to the backend?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the SQL use-case, what you want is a structure representing keys (column names) and values.

You can use [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to create this

```js
const columnValues = Object.fromEntries(
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input.vcheck"), ({ id, value }) => [
    id,
    value,
  ])
);
```

This will look something like this

```js
{
  DEPLOYER_PROJECT: "some value",
  OBJ_TYPE: "some other value",
}
```

You can then send this to your backend to construct your SQL query...

```js
// assuming something like req.body.columnValues

// Valid column names
const COLUMN_NAMES = new Set(["DEPLOYER_PROJECT", "OBJ_TYPE"]);

// array of columns to use in your query
const cols = Object.keys(req.body.columnValues).filter((col) =>
  COLUMN_NAMES.has(col)
);

// array of values to bind in your query
const values = cols.map((col) => req.body.columnValues[col]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the className of the input to loop through it using forEach loop

```js
var getInput = document.querySelectorAll(".vcheck");
    
    getInput.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element.value)
    });
```

Comment: Okay that is returning every value much better to what I need but how would I insert it? I updated my question to include the sql portion but how would I insert the information once it has been log?

Comment: @genericdude76 if the number of inputs you have gonna always be an even number you can try this code `let input = document.querySelectorAll(".vcheck")
   let idx = 0;
   while (input[idx])
   {
        console.log(input[idx].value, input[idx + 1].value);
        idx += 2;
   }`

Comment: That could work. So in my sql string I would DB(INSERT INTO TABLE(DEPLOYER_PROJECT, OBJ_TYPE) VALUES ('" +input[idx].value + "', '" + input[idx + 1].value + "')) ?

Comment: What would I do if I have an uneven number of inputs? Or would I have to just add an additional input field

Comment: @genericdude76 you can add another empty input or use something like this
`let input = document.querySelectorAll(".vcheck")
   let idx = 0;
   while (input[idx])
   {
        if (typeof input[idx + 1] != 'undefined')
        console.log(input[idx].value, input[idx + 1].value)
        else
        console.log(input[idx].value)
        idx += 2;
   }`

Comment: Thank for the suggestion I will try that and see how it works. In my console I am seeing the values properly but in my database it is saying the value is undefine. Do I need to assign a variable to input[idx] and another variable for input[idx+1]?